# Type casting and pointers

Tags: c, types, casting

I have a piece of code I am unsure on would very much appreciate a run down on its workings.

The first bit is about type casting. Can someone tell me if I'm reading the following code correctly:

```
#define A_TIME          0xC0500000
#define B_TIME           *(UINT_8 *)(A_TIME + 0x00002909)
```

Is the output of this that B_TIME is a pointer to an unsigned integer of 8 bits = 0x09?
I'm unsure of how type casting works? Does it assign the 8 LSB to B_TIME? Also, I'm confused by the *(UINT_8 *)? What exactly does this mean/say? It's a pointer to a unsigned integer of 8 bits?

The second part will probably be clear to me once I know the above but I'll post it anyway:

```
UINT_8  Timer = 0;
Input_Time (&Timer);



#define C_TIME                 *(UINT_16 *)0xC0C0B000
#define MASK                        0x003F

void Input_Time (UINT_8 *Time)
{
    *Time = 0xC0;  
    *Time |= (UINT_8)((C_TIME >> 4) & MASK);

    return;
}
```

What is the value of *Time following Input_Time function? Could someone step through the code and explain each step for me?

Apologies for the noviceness (is that a word?!) of the question.

Much appreciated.
James

EDIT:

OK, I'm happy with the above. Thanks. I'm now confused as to the following which happens within the code, after Input_Time() has been called:

```
#define OUT_TIME *(UINT_8 *)0xC0411297
OUT_TIME = Timer;
```

How is this possible? Isn't `OUT_TIME` the 8-bit value within the address 0XC0411297? How does that work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you're looking at looks like it's accessing [memory mapped registers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O).

1. B_TIME will access an 8-bit register located at address `A_TIME` plus the specified offset - in this case, that means `0xC0502909`.  What actually gets read depends on the hardware you're using. Let's break down what happens in pieces.  `B_TIME`, wherever it is used, gets replaced with the text:

   ```
   *(UINT_8 *)(A_TIME + 0x00002909)
   ```

   And in turn, the `A_TIME` is replaced with `0xC0500000`, yielding:

   ```
   *(UINT_8 *)(0xC0500000 + 0x00002909)
   ```

   A little working out of arithmetic gives:

   ```
   *(UINT_8 *)(0xC0502909)
   ```

   Which means "treat `0xC0502909` as a pointer to an 8-bit value and then dereference it".
2. Your second question follows the same behaviour.  There is a register mapped at `0xC0C0B000` that is being read when `Input_Time()` is called.  A 16-bit value is read from that address, is downshifted by 4, and then masked.  Assuming this example 16-bit value, using letters to uniquely represent the bits:

   ```
   abcdefghijklmnop
   ```

   Downshifted by 4:

   ```
   0000abcdefghijkl
   ```

   And then the mask (`3f` hex is `00111111` binary) applied:

   ```
   0000000000ghijkl
   ```

   Then, that result is ORed with the `0xc0` (`11000000` binary), yielding:

   ```
   0000000011ghijkl
   ```

   That value is stored back into the 8-bit passed-in-byte, returning:

   ```
   11ghijkl
   ```

   To the caller.
3. Your new example:

   ```
   #define OUT_TIME *(UINT_8 *)0xC0411297
   OUT_TIME = Timer;
   ```

   Is *writing* a value to that memory address.

Comment: Thank you very much, this makes so much more sense now!

1. So the value of B_TIME is equal to whatever 8-bit value is stored (in RAM) at address 0xC0502909.

2. After you'd cleared up my understanding of 1. part 2. was straight forward to understand.

I have to thank you for taking the time to explain this, especially considering its only been up for such a short time.

Comment: @James, it might not be RAM, but yes.

Answer (score 0):

The value of `B_TIME` is a value of type `UINT8`.

```
#define B_TIME *(UINT_8 *)(A_TIME + 0x00002909)
```

The `*` operator  dereferences the pointer to `UINT8` in the following expression:

`(UINT_8 *)(A_TIME + 0x00002909)`

In the above expression the integer constant expression `A_TIME + 0x00002909` is converted to a pointer to `UINT8` by the mean of the cast `(UINT8 *)`.